# JQuery switch case statement to load from external html file?

Tags: html, jquery

How can I load div content from external file, but also use a case statement in the process?   Might there be something with my Jquery code?  Actually.. I'm confused??

**JQuery Code:**

```
$('.click-test').click(function() {
switch (this.id) {
case "test":
$('#test').load('external-file.html #test');
  break;

  case "test2":
  etc..
  });
```

**html page:**

```
<div class="click-test" id="test">click test</div>
<div id="test">place words from external file here</div>
```

**external file .html**

```
<div id="test">some words</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery code is basically correct. The "this" does refer to the HTML element as you suspected and is set. So, your switch is working.

```
<div class="click-test" id="test">click test</div>
```

However, you've got 2 div's in your base HTML page that both have the ID of "test". Every ID should be unique on an HTML page (including the content you're loading). So, you'll need to do a bit of refactoring.

You could for example change the HTML to:

```
<div class="click-test" data-loadid="test">click test</div>
```

And the JavaScript to:

```
$('.click-test').click(function() {
    switch($(this).attr("data-loadid")) {
```

This would read from an attribute named 'data-loadid' using the jQuery [attribute](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function. Then you can proceed to load the external div content using load as you had done. (Although, you may want to remove the bookmark as it's unnecessary?)

Answer (score 0):

The this.id referes to nothing, since the this object is the .click-test div which has no ID attribute. Everything else looks fine, except I don't know if there should be a space bar after your .html #test

Comment: Both div's have an ID attribute as I mentioned in my answer. Unfortunately, they're the same.

Comment: Hmm I think i missed that the first time I read it. Then the problem is, you got 2 of the same ID's, you cannot have 2 of the same ID's, jQuery will find the first, and does not look for any others.